# Showing the uploaded image in Vaadin with EasyUploads

Tags: image, upload, vaadin, embedded-resource

I'm trying to use [EasyUploads-addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/easyuploads) for Vaadin, but can't get the image shown.

When I click addon's "Choose File"-button, it will ask me to open an file. I choose some .png -file from my images and addon shows the information of the picture beneath it.

Then I press my "Upload"-button, which is currently needed just to show the uploaded image at first.

```
private void showUploadedImage() {
    Object value = upload.getValue();
    byte[] data = (byte[]) value;

    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(
            new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public InputStream getStream() {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }, "filename.png");

    image.setVisible(true);
    image.setCaption("Uploaded image");
    image.setSource(resource);
}
```

upload = EasyUpload's component which is used to choose file

image = Embedded component that I have drawn with the designer to my layout.

But when I look the page with browser the image is not shown. The image is just shown as there is no image at all, just caption will be shown.

HTML-code of the image from the page's source:

```html
<img src="null">
```

This might be really trivial case, but all the examples that I found was over 3-4 years old and didn't look helpful.

Can someone tell me, how it should be done?

Comment: Your code does not compile. You need to make byte[] data final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call a setter on UploadField class:

```
uploadField.setFieldType(FieldType.BYTE_ARRAY);
```

Working SSCCE:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    setContent(layout);
    final UploadField uploadField = new UploadField();
    uploadField.setAcceptFilter(".png");
    uploadField.setFieldType(FieldType.BYTE_ARRAY);
    uploadField.addListener(new Listener(){
        @Override
        public void componentEvent(Event event)
        {
            showUploadedImage(uploadField);
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(uploadField);
    layout.addComponent(image);
}

private void showUploadedImage(UploadField upload) {
    Object value = upload.getValue();
    final byte[] data = (byte[]) value;

    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(
            new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
                @Override
                public InputStream getStream() {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }, "filename.png");

    image.setSource(resource);
}
```

Produces (after choosing a .png file): [image: winniethepooh]

Of course you may want to change type of uploadField listener to more specific one.
Tested on Java 8, Vaadin 7.4.1, Eclipse Luna.